# Definition of a measure over a $\pi$-system

Tags: measure-theory

The following problem might be trivial, nevertheless the solution is not completely clear to me.

Consider a function $f:(0,+\infty)^2\mapsto [0, \infty)$ and impose

$$
\mu((x, + \infty)\times(y, +\infty)):=f(x,y), \qquad \forall(x,y) \in (0,+\infty)^2.
$$

Under which conditions on $f$ can we claim that there exists a measure $\tilde{\mu}$ on

$$
((0,+\infty)^2, \mathcal{B}((0,+\infty)^2))
$$ 
such that $\tilde{\mu}(A)=\mu(A)$ for every set $A$ in the $\pi$-system 
$$ 
\{ (x, +\infty)\times(y, +\infty) \text{:} \, (x,y)\in(0, +\infty)^2\},
$$
on which $\mu$ has been defined?

I would say that one necessary condition is that, defining for every $y \in(0, +\infty)$ the projection map 
$$f_y:(0,+\infty)\mapsto[0,+\infty):x\mapsto f(x,y)
$$ 
and for every $x \in(0, +\infty)$ the projection map
$$
f_x:(0,+\infty)\mapsto[0,+\infty):y\mapsto f(x,y),
$$ 
$f_y$ and $f_x$ are monotone non-increasing. Yet, I think such restriction is not sufficient. Which other properties have to be satisfied by $f$?

Comment: I just add a comment: here I would eventually allow $\tilde{\mu}$ to have infinite mass on $(0, +\infty)^2$. My doubts rise from this point. I see that if we restricted our attention to finite measure, then it is possible to proceed as in the case in which we specify a measure starting from a bivariate distribution function.

Comment: A further remark: letting $t(x,y)=(x^{-1},y^{-1})$, $\forall (x,y) \in (0,+\infty)^2$, one may think to specify a measure $\lambda$ such that $\lambda(t(A))=\mu(A)$. In particular, $\lambda$ can be specified on the rectangles $(a_1,b_1]\times(a_2,b_2] \subset (0, +\infty)^2$ via $\lambda((a_1,b_1]\times(a_2,b_2])=f(b_1^{-1},b_2^{-1})-f(b_1^{-1},a_2^{-1})-f(a_1^{-1},b_2^{-1})+f(a_1^{-1},a_2^{-1})$ provided that $f$ is continuous and such expression is positive. But in order such expression to be positive, i think we need more than the above condition on the projections $f_x$ and $f_y$.